# Model if logic not working correctly

Tags: django

Why won't my logic work to verify if a field in my custom user model named formattedusername is equal to a field my QvDatareducecfo model using the def cfo defined below.

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    username = models.CharField(max_length=7, unique=True)
    formattedusername = models.CharField(max_length=11, unique=True, primary_key = True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_cfo = models.BooleanField(default=False)




    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'accounts'
        db_table = "user"

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.formattedusername = '{domain}\{username}'.format(
            domain='HCA', username=self.username)
        super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs);

    def cfo(self):
        cfo = self.QvDatareducecfo.cfo_ntname
        if  self.formattedusername == cfo:
            self.is_cfo = 1
        else:
            self.is_cfo = 0
        print (is_cfo)
        super(User, self).save(is_cfo)


#    REQUIRED_FIELDS = "username"

    def __str__(self):
        return "@{}".format(self.username)
```

I defined the cfo_ntame field as a OneToOneField in the QvDatareducecfo model.  I don't receive an error message on my logic and it looks like return is_cfo prints a 0, but if i update the cfo table to a 1 and re-login it doesn't update to a 0 and the user id i'm using isn't listed in the cfo table.

```
QvDatareduceCfo Model:

class QvDatareducecfo(models.Model):

    cfo_ntname = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,db_column='CFO_NTName',primary_key=True, serialize=False, max_length=7)  # Field name made lowercase.
    cfo_type = models.IntegerField(db_column='CFO_Type', blank=True, null=True)  

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'QV_DataReduceCFO'
```

Comment: can you paste your QvDatareducecfo model here ? What is relationship between QvDatareducecfo and User models ?

Comment: I added the model for QvDatareducecfo.  The relationship is a OneToOneField on settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL formattedusername.

Comment: If you do not specify the related_name argument for the OneToOneField, Django will use the lower-case name of the current model as default value. So change self.QvDatareducecfo.cfo_ntname  to self.qvdatareducecfo.cfo_ntname

Comment: When I change it and call the def cfo in my save, it gives me the following error: django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: User has no qvdatareducecfo.

Comment: where are you creating the qvdatareducecfo record ? you need to create the record and set the reference to the corresponding user record.

Comment: qvdatareducecfo is another model which is a pre-exisiting database table i'm just reading from i.e. manged = False, am i not able to access another model from a model? Maybe that's what i'm having issues with.

Comment: you have one to one relationship between user and qvdatareducecfo .. so after creating both records, you need to set up the relationship between both records. eg. qv = QvDatareducecfo()  qv.cfo_ntname = user   qv.save() .. In the above snippet am creating a relationship when qvdata is saved.

Comment: You are great Saji, thank you very much for the clear and concise explanation.  How can I give you credit for the correct answer?  If i'm never saving qvdatareduce and just reading from a SQL database doing self.user.formattedusername = qv.cfo_ntname works.

Comment: good, I have added it as answer please accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues that need to be addressed,

1. Issue with the related name.

If you do not specify the related_name argument for the OneToOneField,
Django will use the **lower-case** name of the current model as
default value. So change to

```
def cfo(self):
    cfo = self.qvdatareducecfo.cfo_ntname
```

2. If you are getting RelatedObjectDoe‌​sNotExist error while accessing self.qvdatareducecfo then you have to create a qvr record and set the reference to the corresponding 'user' record. 
   eg:

   qv=QvDatareducecfo()
   qv.cfo_ntname = user
   qv.save()